# PHP Show options depending on the selected year

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to show options to the user according to the year he's selecting.
At the top of the file I have a function to retrieve the year, and send it back to the same page which is view2.php, but I'm sure I'm doing it wrong:

```
if(!empty($_POST['year'])){
    $year = htmlentities($_POST['year']);
    header('Location: view2.php');
    //exit();
}
```

Later, I have a form submitting the year that looks like this

```
    <form method="post" action="">

    Select year:
    <?php
        $myOptions = array(
            'All' => 'All',
            '2013' => '2013', 
            '2014' => '2014', 
            '2015' => '2015', 
            '2016' => '2016', 
            '2017' => '2017', 
            '2018' => '2018', 
            '2019' => '2019', 
            '2020' => '2020' 

        );
    ?>
    <select name="year">
        <?php
        foreach($myOptions as $key => $opt) {
            $selected = null;

        if(isset($_POST['View All']) && $key === $_POST['View All'])
            $selected = ' selected';

        echo '<option value="' . $key . '"' . $selected. '>' . $opt . '</option>';
        }
        ?>  
    </select>       
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="GO"/>
    </form>
```

If I manually set the `$year` variable, my sql query works fine, so the function (`$users->expensePerYear($username, $year, $i);`) is okay. This is my function:

```
    <?php
    $i=0;
    $year = 2013;
        //if (isset($year)){
        $users->expensePerYear($username, $year, $i);
        $userQueryResult = $users->queryResult;
        $count = $users->i;
        $totalSpent = $users->totalSpent;
        $remaining = $budget-$totalSpent;
```

The problem is that I'm trying to send the year variable to the same page and I'm doing it wrong. I want the user to specify the year in the select, send it to the same page and show stuff according to that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind me, I only had to comment the header() line and it works.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) {
    $year = htmlentities($_POST['year']);
    //header('Location: view2.php?$year=".$year."');
    //echo $year;
}
```